# Single website really slow on only one computer with all browsers

Tags: internet, website

A single website is very slow on one computer. It takes about 15 seconds to load the website. This website only shows the text `test`.

To make sure the website is not slow I tried pingdom and google pagespeed and both get the website within 0.5 seconds. I also tried it from my mobile phone which is connected to the same WiFi network where the computer does not work and it also loads within 0.5 seconds.

Things I have tried which didn't work

- Clearing the cache.
- Incognito tab
- Rebooting the computer
- Different browsers
- Changed my DNS-address to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
- Tried with cable and with WiFi
- Tried disabling other network adapters.

What else could I try?

This is the website: https://linq.tech/

Network tab in google chrome. Shows 15 seconds to load 53B.
[image: slow load]
[image: tracert]
[image: ping]

**UPDATE:**
After testing out on a laptop it also took longer than 15 seconds! So I guess it's an issue with the router/modem.

What I've tried

- Restarting the modem/router.

Comment: I tested this website and it doesn't even have HTML code. It is just providing the string '      test'. But - it is fast...

Comment: @zx485 I can't figure out why it's just this single computer that is slow.

Comment: Have you tested other Windows machines on your LAN, or are you going (just) by the fact that your phone loaded it fast?  Have you got an AV/Internet protection suite installed?  If you boot into Safe Mode with Networking, does it load the page any faster? If you boot your computer to a LinuxLive CD, does it load the page any faster?

Comment: I tested this on a different laptop connected with LAN it took also longer than 15 seconds on the laptop! So this makes me think that the issue now is my modem/router. I've tried restarting the modem/router. It didn't work. I  only have the default Windows Defender on both systems. I haven't tried the LinuxLive CD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what was wrong.

I thought it was only on my PC but at one of my friends house it loaded in 15 seconds or so and at another friends house it loaded within 0.5 seconds. I had no more ideas as to where to search for this problem anymore and was almost going to change hosting companies. My friend told me if I was using a proxy on my website. I said no. But then I thought I do use cloudflare.

So I tried disabling cloudflare and it didn't work. After that I tried changing nameservers and waited until it was changed for the world.

The next day I went on to my website and it loaded fast! I pressed refresh 50x times and I was sure it had worked. I called my friend where my website didn't work and asked him if he could try going to my website. He said it loaded fast.

Cloudflare for some reason was the issue. I don't know what the issue is. But it was Cloudflare and I am happy this is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

That may be network problem in your lan.
Connect to router only your laptop, using working cable.
If problem still exist, then this is probably caused by your router.
if not, then you should check: cables, switch, IP conflicts.