# One website loads very slowly on one computer. It loads fine on all other computers

Tags: router, dns, ip, website

When a user tries to connect to https://www.panelook.com. It loads extremely slow or not at all sometimes. When I use it on my own computer or any other computer within the same network, it works fine. All the computers have the same IP configuration, DNS, subnet and gateway. When I do a tracert both computers go through exactly the same routes/hops. I've tried everything that I could, but I have no idea why it doesn't work. Here are the things I've tried:

- FlushDNS
- Ipconfig renew
- Netsh winsock reset
- SFC scan
- Chkdsk
- Used different VLANS (all have the same issue with this computer, other PC's work well)
- Rebooted the computer
- Rebooted the router
- Rerouted it through a different router
- This: [Single website really slow on only one computer with all browsers](https://superuser.com/questions/1149820/single-website-really-slow-on-only-one-computer-with-all-browsers)
- Tested all VLANS. All goes well, except for this computer
- Checked anti-virus just in case
- Checked the firewall

All to no avail.

I have no idea where the problem lies and the user used this site in the past every day to make his work a bit more easier and nothing major has changed on the internet line that could've caused this.

Comment: Is this one computer slow on other websites?

Comment: @harrymc No it isn't. It's just this one particular website that is slow. other websites are loading just fine.

Comment: Which browsers has your friend tried

Comment: Google Chrome, FireFox and Microsoft Edge.

Comment: Are all systems using the same DNS server(s) settings, or does that one user use different ones?

Comment: All the computers use the same DNS settings yeah.

Comment: hm, is the website using IPv6, and maybe either the website or the friend's computer slightly misconfigured? IPv6 is absolutely standard these days, but there's still the occasional misconfigured server or client.

Comment: Just to let you know that my Firefox-based browser has just hung when I tried to access this website. It hang on "Performinq a TLS handshake to www.panelook.com...". But Chrome had no problem. I think that this computer of yours is missing some TLS ciphers, so has a problem doing the handshake with this website and finding an agreed-upon cipher.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I opened it in my Firefox and it loaded just fine although to be honest, it did hang for 2 seconds on Performing TLS handshake.And I don't think the site is using IPv6 because I get a IPv4 response when I ping or is there an other way to check if the site is using IPv6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've installed feature update 22H2 and a couple of security updates for his computer and it seems that the website is a bit faster now. Not like it's suppose to, but at least he can work with it. Thanks for the suggestions about TLS Ciphers